# Do the moderators here have the ability to delete Buddhism.StackExchange accounts?

Tags: support, status-completed

I've already requested deletion from the StackExchange staff but it seems to be taking rather a long time. Do the MPTs have that power?

Comment: Short answer is yes. Are you sure? There's no undo.

Comment: Yes, please. I've made several requests.  But just from Buddhism and Buddhism Meta.  I have other accounts that I'm fairly active on. Thank you!

Comment: It says on your Buddhism user page that your account is scheduled for deletion in 23 hours. The meta page doesn't have the notice, but I assume it will disappear as well...

Comment: Your request has gone through (one of the SE employees or other moderators got to it) and the account is scheduled for deletion in 23 (and change) hours.  The meta page is linked to your main profile page, so it doesn't need to be deleted separately. Your other accounts should not be touched.

Comment: Much obliged.  :-)