# How do I close my Buddhism account?

Tags: support

I have visited the links [This](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202/closing-buddhism-stack-exchange-account) and [This](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158/do-the-moderators-here-have-the-ability-to-delete-buddhism-stackexchange-account)

But it doesn't tell me how to close the account without affecting other SE accounts (Unless I missed something... Apologies for that)

How can I close it? If a mod can take down my request, I would be really grateful.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this help page has the information you were looking for: [How do I delete my account?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account)

It says,

> If you have voted or posted, please contact the Stack Exchange Team:
>
> Visit the [contact form](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/contact) and select 'I need to delete my user profile.' After you contact us, the team will reach out with further instructions.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I hope my other profiles will be untouched if i use the form mentioned in the above contact form?

Comment: I got this email "You recently sent a request to have your Buddhism Stack Exchange profile removed. We're sorry to see you go! This email is just to let you know your request has been received, and we will respond with help ASAP." So I guess my other profiles are safe :) Thanks a lot again.